# Does git clone include commit comments too?

Tags: git

I'm backing up git hub and bitbucket.
Does git clone include commit comments too?
if I do a git log in the directory, I'm able to see commit history.
How do I see commit comments

Comment: Do you mean comments the author has made during the commit process, or comments others have made inline on Github or Bitbucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

When you clone you get all the commits + tags + notes + messages.

Type a `git log` and you will see it all

In git you have the option to add notes as well as comments, you will get athem all as well.

- **To view history (log):**

  ```
  git log
  ```
- **To view all branches:**

  ```
  git branch -a
  ```
- **To view all tags:**

  ```
  git tag -l
  ```
- **If you wish to see all your current branches log history:***

  ```
  git log --oneline --decorate --graph
  ```

Comment: I don't think that's what he means. He is referring to comments made from the website

Comment: Hello,
I meant for comments made on the commits in the website.
I do not see them when I do a git log.


When I do a git log:

commit 8577feq232sdsc1313193a5e7368
Author: unknown <username@domai.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 22 15:14:02 2014 -0400

    no message

Comment: You mean the comments form pull request on form the web interface? those one you cant get. they are stored in the DB and are not part of git.

Comment: @CodeWizard
When we commit changes, we can include a note and comment on the commits in the web.
Can we get these comments or are they stored in db too?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: They are stored in the DB, they are not part of GIt in any way so you cant grab them.

Comment: @CodeWizard Thank you.

Comment: Sure, You can accept the answer if it helped you out. Good luck.